# How to add django modules to pydiction dictionary?

Tags: python, django, vim

I'm trying to use pydiction to autocomplete Python/Django statements in VIM Editor.

When I try to add django modules to complete-dic using this:

```
python pydiction.py /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django
```

or:

```
python pydiction.py /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/__init__.py
```

I receive this error:

Couldn't import: (...). Import by filename is not supported.

Thanks!

Pydiction: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=850

Answer (score 6):

It is quite some time since this question was raised. I faced similar problem. Following steps explain how to do it somewhat quickly.

Since pydiction.py doesn't parse packages recursively, I had to use find and vi to build a package list for Django. Suppose you have installed django in `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django.` Then do the following:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
find django -type d > /var/tmp/django_pkgs.sh
```

Open django_pkgs.sh in vim and delete all lines containing media, static, templates, gis, fixtures, tests, locale, localflavor etc. In vim, it is easy. Do the following from the vim console itself:

```
:g/media/d
:g/static/d
:g/templates/d
....
....
....
```

Once all unwanted files are removed from our listing, replace all / with . Do the following from within vim console:

```
:%s!/!.!g
```

This will convert the file path to fully qualified Python module names. Then replace all newlines with white space. Do the following from within the vim console:

```
%s/\n/ /
```

Note that there is a single white space character between last two forward slashes.
Now you have all module names listed in a single line. Now add #!/bin/bash in the first line of the file. This way, we are converting our file into a bash script. Now add the following on second and third lines (as explained by oivvio in one of the earlier posts):

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/parent/of/settings
```

Please replace path mentioned in the last line with the directory where your django settings.py is kept.

Then at the beginning of the line listing django modules, add the following

```
python ./pydiction.py
```

This line now should look like

```
python ./pydiction.py django django.contrib django.contrib.redirects ......
```

Now exit vim and run

```
chmod +x /var/tmp/django_pkgs.sh.
```

Then change to the directory where complete-dict and pydiction.py is kept and execute `/var/tmp/django_pkgs.sh`. You do need write access to the file complete-dict. If your package listing file is correct, everything will work fine. Otherwise you will see various errors on the console caused by importing of non-existing django modules. To fix them, identify such entries in your `django_pkgs.sh` file and remove them manually. Then again execute the same script.

I would have preferred `pydiction.py` doing a recursive search of modules rather than everyone preparing the module list manually. Probably a command line argument like -r could have been added to pydiction to do this automatically. :(

Comment: ok i ended up with 10gb file, which being scanned in VIm for like 5 hours.. =/

Answer (score 1):

By glancing at the pydiction docs (I'm not a pydiction user) it appears that you are misusing the `pydiction.py` script.

You are not supposed to provide a filename for import. You are supposed to provide a module name on which to base the dictionary creation. The module must already be in your pythonpath.

So, with django in your pythonpath, you would do:

`python pydiction.py django`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason doing

```
python pydiction.py django
```

will not add the submodules of django

What I had to do was:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/parent/of/settings
```

And then I had to add each submodule of django individually

```
python pydiction.py django.bin
python pydiction.py django.conf
python pydiction.py django.contrib
```

And so on. Tedious but it works